# Dividing an integral by the integral of the same function with different bounds

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I've learned in Calculus 2 that

$$\int_a^b{f(x)dx} + \int_b^c{f(x)dx} = \int_a^c{f(x)dx}$$

so I was wondering if a similar thing existed for multiplications and divisions:

$$\large\frac{\int_a^b{f(x)dx}}{\int_a^c{f(x)dx}}$$

Is there any way to simplify this? What I'm trying to simplify is

$$\Large\frac{\int_{[A]_0}^{[A]_{t_1}}{\frac{d[A]}{[A]^n}}}{\int_{[A]_0}^{[A]_{t_2}}{\frac{d[A]}{[A]^n}}} = \frac{t_1}{t_2}$$

Where $[A]$ is the concentration of the any A element (in chemistry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no analogous rule. Just compute your integrals using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. (It would look less scary if you wrote $\int_a^b x^{-n}\,dx$.)